# WooCommerce query order totals grouped by users with specific role

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to list all users with a specific role (custom role 'forhandler') and for each show their totals (spent) on published orders that have status 'completed', 'processing' and 'on-hold', along with a count of the number of orders per user (also published and status as above). The result must be sorted with the highest totals first.

I managed to write a SQL query that works (and that's the limit of my SQL knowledge), but it takes 20 seconds+ when running on production data (1200 orders and increasing). Can this query be rewritten to something more efficient (or simply better)?

```
SELECT users.ID, users.display_name,
(SELECT COUNT(posts.ID)
FROM $wpdb->posts AS posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->postmeta.post_id = posts.ID
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS rel ON posts.ID=rel.object_ID
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tax USING( term_taxonomy_id )
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms AS term USING( term_id )
WHERE $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_customer_user'
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = users.ID
AND posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
AND posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND tax.taxonomy = 'shop_order_status'
AND term.slug IN ('completed', 'processing', 'on-hold')
) AS numOrders,
(
SELECT SUM(postmeta.meta_value)
FROM $wpdb->postmeta AS postmeta
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->posts AS pp ON pp.ID = postmeta.post_id
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS pm2 ON pm2.post_id = postmeta.post_id
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS rel ON pp.ID=rel.object_ID
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tax USING( term_taxonomy_id )
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms AS term USING( term_id )
WHERE postmeta.meta_key = '_order_total'
AND pm2.meta_key = '_customer_user'
AND pm2.meta_value = users.ID
AND tax.taxonomy = 'shop_order_status'
AND term.slug IN ('completed', 'processing', 'on-hold')
AND pp.post_type = 'shop_order'
AND pp.post_status = 'publish'
) AS totalsOfOrders
FROM wp_users AS users
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id
WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' 
AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%forhandler%'
ORDER BY totalsOfOrders DESC
```

Comment: It can certainly be written more elegantly. More efficient? Without running a direct comparison, and seeing the EXPLAIN for each, it's hard (for me) to say. BTW, your WHERE clauses render those LEFT JOINs as INNER JOINs. Presumably you have values for all keys, which is why you didn't notice.

Comment: Also, those corellating bits ("AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = users.ID") are likely to be really slow. I'd suggest a fix but to be honest I don't even understand how that bit works!